# How does one check for join table association in AREL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause, arel

Basically I'm looking for the AREL, version of this working method :

```
@jobs.select{|a| !a.assignments.present? }
```

Assuming AREL or a `where` statement would be more proper *and* faster. How would one write that *faster* than what I have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a `Job has_many assignments`

```
@jobs.where('id in (select j.id from jobs j inner join assignments a on a.job_id=j.id)')
```

Comment: Correct assumption. Question though, would this SQL select statement be equivalent to the rails one? In that it iterates through each object and performs a method?

Comment: No, it will be a single select with a subquery, returning an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You can try it out in the Rails console and see the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
Job.joins(:assignments).where('assignments.present' => false)
```

executes the this sql:

```
 SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "assignments"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE "assignments"."present" = 't'
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the specific instant variable I'm using though.

Comment: which specific instant variable??

Comment: `@jobs` . Your match selects the Job class. But I'd like to select out of the instance variable `@jobs`